# Using SSL with UDP

Tags: c++, c, sockets, ssl, udp

Is it possible to use SSL with UDP for sockets?
I know how to create TCP socket with SSL, 
s = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
And then I can use OpenSSL with it, but what about UDP (SOCK_DGRAM)?

P.S. I want to use OpenSSL

Comment: [THIS](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/51590/how-do-ssl-authenticated-users-prove-authenticity-through-udp-packets) may help

Answer (score 9):

So it is possible! The protocol is named `DTLS` and *Openssl* provide an implementation. You can find the API here [Openssl documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/)
I didn't find any tutorial for DTLS...

Comment: the link does not work anymore